# Is there a way I can change the URL displayed in the Facebook snippet using open graph protocol?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a website that resides at:

http://s278184750.onlinehome.us

I have a sub-domain (webdesign.kyle-co.com) that points to the above address.

Is there a way to make the Facebook snippet display the sub-domain name rather than  http://s278184750.onlinehome.us ?

Comment: Move the website to webdesign.kyle-co.com

Comment: Not while “pointing to” means a redirect to the first URL. You need to make your content available directly under the second domain, not have it redirect elsewhere.